# How would you handle creating a response for a method that checks if an object is valid?

Tags: django

Lets say I have a Model in my models.py that stores financial transactions. The model has a method called is_valid() which basically checks that the object adheres to a bunch of business logics.

This method has now got quite long, it does about 20 checks on the object and looks something like this:

```
    def is_valid(self):
        if self.something is something:
            return false
        if self.something_else is something:
            return false
        ...
        return true
```

So far this has worked great, but I've now got to the stage where I no longer need to just know if an object is valid, but if it's not valid I need to know which check it failed. So something like:

```
    def is_valid(self):
        if self.something is something:
            return error1
        if self.something_else is something:
            return error2
        ...
        return true
```

But, if the object has failed multiple checks then I'd want to know all the checks it has failed.

What would be the most clean way of handling this?

My code also has lots of lines that check is_valid() returns true, so ideally it would still return true if the object is valid, but if not valid then it would let me know which conditions it failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is you can do..

```
def is_valid(self):
    if self.something is something:
        return False, error1
    if self.something_else is something:
        return False, error2
    ...
    return True, 'Yeahhh!!!'
```

Now you can check using...

```
status, msg = self.is_valid()
if status:
   print("Valid")
else:
    print(msg)
```

Let me know if your problem still persists...